# Programatically make LinearLayout dismissible in android studio using shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**There is this thing I want to achieve, I have searched all questions on SO and no answer related to this, so I guess no one has asked which makes me curious.**

On my XML, Android studio app, I added a Linear Layout, under the Linear layout, I added a 《TextView with text "Dismiss"》.

I want to set an onclick listener to this textview, once user clicks this TextView with text "Dismiss" I don't want that user to see that Linear Layout again on the page until they reinstall the app.

Logically, the Linear Layout will be like a notice to highlight something on my app when users arrive at that page, but instead of that notice to stay there forever I want user to be able to dismiss it which shows they have gotten the notice.

**My workings:**

1. Since I want each app user to decide not to see that text again after clicking dismiss, I need to use shared preference on that TextView with text "Dismiss", so whenever app gets the value of this shared preference then it will hide that layout.
2. I can set the LinearLayout to be invisible if that value from shared preference is found when stored on the app
3. The question now, how will I set this shared preference and which code will I use to make the Layout "GONE" or "INVISIBLE" if the TextView with text "Dismiss" is clicked?

Your intelligent solution to this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out , its in Java, and this will hide the layout after clicking the dismisstextview and when u re open it alert will still be hidden.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),0);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();

        LinearLayout alertLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alertLayout);
        TextView textViewDismiss = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewDismiss);

        if(sharedPref.getBoolean("isLayoutAlertShown",false)){
            alertLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            alertLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        textViewDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                editor.putBoolean("isLayoutAlertShown",true);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what should I use to initialize the shared preference, would it be "Private SharedPreferences sharedPref;" being added just under import, or ......and where should I put the first block of code, is it inside or outside oncreate?

Comment: @Karmar the 'Private SharedPreferences sharedPref;' should be inside the class before Oncreate method, everything else should be inside the OnCreate method, also this is Kotlin code, if you are using Java dont forget to convert it into Java code

Comment: My code is in java, can you provide java solution, I tried to convert but it's throughing error using the android studio conversion tool, please help

Comment: @Karmar, I edited the code and changed from Kotlin to Java, and I added the full Activity Java class code, hope it helps :)

Comment:  I don't know what I would have done with you brainy. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `SharedPreferences` since this is related to setting matter. You can refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

You have to call this method at the `onCreate`. So it will check if the there is `showLayout` stated `true` or `false`, then it will update the design.

```
//Inside onCreate
private void initSharedPreference(final Activity activity, final LinearLayout linearLayout) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPref.getBoolean("showLayout", false)) {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

At the `setOnClickListener` you need to implement this method.

```
//At the button
private void setSharedPrefShowLayout(final Activity activity, final Boolean isVisible) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("showLayout", isVisible);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Hello, I placed the first  code after setContentView. The ("final Activity activity," the opening and closing bracket has a red mark and error shows **';'expected** the middle final says **Identifier expectes**, what to do? Thanks

Comment: No.. what I mean is that the method is inside the class. Call the the method inside the `onCreate`. Do you understand? @Karmar

Comment: I am still getting error, see the placement on the screenshot https://snipboard.io/rgRSXv.jpg

Comment: you placed it wrong . Put it outside the `onCreate`. Call it inside the `onCreate` @Karmar

Comment: Thank you, now that you said outside oncreate, it's clear and there is no error, but which method should I use to call it Inside oncreate? Like which line of code should be added to call this code you created? The help is really appreciated, thank you for looking into it.